# Product Type is invalid or not supported even when uploading the CSV magento exported

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport, products-management

I am trying to upload a csv file containing all of my products to my magento 1.9 installation. When I go to import and select the CSV file, and click check data I get this error message 'Product Type is invalid or not supported' and its saying its for all of my products.

Even if I export the current products on the website as a CSV and reupload them I get the same error.

Any idea why this is happening or how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing this problem but a work around would be using magmi to import your products.

Answer (score 5):

When exporting products in Magento, "Bundle" and "Downloadable" products can't be re-imported using the default importer (Or data flow) so these could be what is throwing the error message. If you are using these product types I would recommend using Magmi as this imports Bundle and Downloadable products as well as being easier to use (In my experience at least)

Magmi has good documentation which can be found here - http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page